# Any reference to free internet time web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, datetime

I need to get real-time information about Date and Time for my application. FYI, i develop an app for a TV, so there's no reliable local-machine time like we got from new Date(). I use javascript for the development.

My plan is to get the time from a server. But I don't have a server for this project, so I can't set any server-side scripting to handle this. All i need is a free web service that provide Date and Time info. Any references?

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

take a look at http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now
a simple ajax call to it should return the current time.

Comment: I found this service to be too slow

Comment: the service is down sometimes :(

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be helpful for you: http://time.gov/aboutB.html

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the actual webservice address from that page. Is it https://www.time.gov/actualtime.cgi or something else?